# How do i generate key pairs using curve25519 libsodium in PYTHON?

Tags: python, libsodium

Is there a way to generate public and private keypair using libsodium? I tried using the function crypto_box_keypair, but I keep getting an error. I've been searching online for information, however, the ones that I've found are either not in python or they don't work. I would appreciate if someone help me.

This are my codes which i did in python so far.

```
   import pysodium
   private_key = pysodium.crypto_box_keypair()
   public_key = pysodium.crypto_box_keypair()

   print("Private Key:", private_key)
   print("Public Key:", public_key)
```

The error I got was:

```
   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'crypto_box_keypair'
```

Comment: Did you by accident name your file `pysodium.py`?

Comment: @KlausD. i didn't but it still didnt work.